# Parse hours without leading zeroes by strptime in Python

Tags: python, time, strptime

Suppose you have time in this format:

```
a = [..., 800.0, 830.0, 900.0, 930.0, 1000.0, 1030.0, ...]
```

The problem is that leading zeroes for hours are missing. For example `00:30` is represented by `30`, `08:00` is represented by `800.` and `00:00` is represented by `2400`.
Is it possible to parse this data to `time` object using `strptime` method?
I tried using following code

```
hours = [time.strptime(str(int(i)), "%H%M") for i in a]
```

but got

```
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 0
```

P.S. I'm using Python 2.7.

Comment: Are those meant to be strings? If so, you need to add `''` quotes around the values.

Comment: @MartijnPieters these are actually `float` in the list, therefore I convert them to `int` to get rid of the trailing dot, but I think I like your method more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `zfill` to add those zeros back as needed:

```
hours = [time.strptime(i[:-1].zfill(4), "%H%M") for i in a]
```

By using `i[:-1]` we remove that pesky trailing dot, and `.zfill(4)` will add enough `0` characters to the left to make it to 4 digits.

Demo:

```
>>> import time
>>> a = ['800.', '830.', '900.', '30.']
>>> [time.strptime(i[:-1].zfill(4), "%H%M") for i in a]
[time.struct_time(tm_year=1900, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=8, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=-1), time.struct_time(tm_year=1900, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=8, tm_min=30, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=-1), time.struct_time(tm_year=1900, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=9, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=-1), time.struct_time(tm_year=1900, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=0, tm_min=30, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=-1)]
```

If they are float values instead, use the [`format()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) on them to give you zero-padded values:

```
>>> format(800., '04.0f')
'0800'
```

So do this:

```
hours = [time.strptime(format(i % 2400, '04.0f'), "%H%M") for i in a]
```

where `% 2400` normalizes your values to the 0. to 2399. range.

Answer (score 3):

You can extract hours, minutes without `strptime()` in this case:

```
>>> from datetime import time
>>> a = [800., 830., 900., 930., 1000., 1030., 30., 2400.]
>>> [time(*divmod(int(f) % 2400, 100)) for f in a]
[datetime.time(8, 0), 
 datetime.time(8, 30), 
 datetime.time(9, 0), 
 datetime.time(9, 30),
 datetime.time(10, 0),
 datetime.time(10, 30),
 datetime.time(0, 30),
 datetime.time(0, 0)]
```

If you want to use `strptime()` for whatever reason; you could concisely get the required format using `x % y`:

```
>>> ["%04.0f" % (f % 2400) for f in a]
['0800', '0830', '0900', '0930', '1000', '1030', '0030', '0000']
```

Answer (score 1):

If those are really float literals in there vs strings, you can do this:

```
a=[800., 830., 900., 930., 1000., 1030.]
hours=[time.strptime('{:04.0f}'.format(f), '%H%M') for f in a]
```

That will round the decimal if any (`1033.66666` would be `1034` hence becoming `10:34 AM`)

You can also truncate like so:

```
[800.0, 830.0, 900.0, 930.0, 1000.0, 1030.0, 1033.3333333, 1033.66666]
hours=[time.strptime(str(f).split('.')[0], '%H%M') for f in a]
```

---

*edit from comments*

If you have values outside the range, you do this:

```
a=[800., 830., 900., 930., 1000., 1030., 2400.]
hours=[time.strptime(s,'%H%M') for s in ['{:04.0f}'.format(f) if f <2400 else '0000' for f in a]]
```

or, you can make your original code work that way as well:

```
[time.strptime(i,'%H%M') for i in[str(int(f)) if f<2400 else '0000' for f in a]]
```